# ImGUI: How to get draw-call count

Tags: imgui

To issue ImGUI draw commands, the code is something like this:

```cpp
    ImDrawData* imDrawData = ImGui::GetDrawData();
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < imDrawData->CmdListsCount; i++) {
        const ImDrawList* cmdList = imDrawData->CmdLists[i];
        for (int32_t j = 0; j < cmdList->CmdBuffer.Size; j++) {
           // DrawCall(...)
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to know the draw call count prior to iterating over the ImGUI structs?

It would be nice to have something like `imDrawData->DrawCallCount`.

This can be used to setup draw data structs prior to performing the iterations.